# affinity analysis using arules "apriori" is giving me zero rules

Tags: r, arules, market-basket-analysis

I am R version 3.4.4 on a Windows 10 machine, and starting with a CSV that looks like this. it has 4247 entries:

```
  student_id course
1          1  EC402
2          2  EC403
3          3  EC403
4          4  FI201
5          4  LA321
6          4  LA325
```

I know R won't do much of anything with it in this format. I found this for help: [How to prep transaction data into basket for arules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997410/how-to-prep-transaction-data-into-basket-for-arules)

So I applied that to my data frame:

```
require(arules)
trans <- as(split(df[,"course"],df[,"student_id"],), "transactions")
```

I go to inspect the transactions, so far, so good. Here's a small snippit:

```
[14]   {MG900,MK605}                                     14           
[15]   {AC103,EC402,QA811}                               15           
[16]   {EC403,LA301}                                     16           
[17]   {EC408}                                           17           
[18]   {AC111,AC115,LA325,MG503}                         18           
[19]   {EC403}                                           19           
[20]   {QA811}                                           20           
[21]   {MG962}                                           21           
[22]   {AC104,FI201,MG535,MG565}                         22           
[23]   {FI234,FI253,PO000}                               23           
[24]   {EC411}                                           24           
[25]   {CO810,MK611,PO000,SP596}                         25
```

But now I want to get some rules of association, and it gives me zero rules.

```
rules <- apriori(trans, parameter = list(supp = 0.2, conf = 0.8))
```

The output:

```
Parameter specification:
 confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport maxtime support minlen
        0.8    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE       5     0.2      1
 maxlen target   ext
     10  rules FALSE

Algorithmic control:
 filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
    0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

Absolute minimum support count: 329 

set item appearances ...[0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
set transactions ...[153 item(s), 1645 transaction(s)] done [0.00s].
sorting and recoding items ... [0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
creating transaction tree ... done [0.00s].
checking subsets of size 1 done [0.00s].
writing ... [0 rule(s)] done [0.00s].
creating S4 object  ... done [0.00s].
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong, or perhaps a different way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing the confidence and the support to for example 0.1 both to see if you get rules ?. It could be that the thresholds are not exceeded

Comment: Oops, yes, that was it! Thank you.

Comment: Perfect then !; Mark it as solved :)